# undeclared variable in a do-while loop in C

Tags: c, loops, do-while, undeclared-identifier

I want to use a variable that i receive from the user to further frame a condition in a loop.

```
do
{
    int sp= get_int("Enter the start size of llama population:");

}
while (sp>=9);
```

how shall i fix this error? i am new to C

I wanted the sp variable to receive an input greater or equal to 9, and if not, i wanted to prompt the user again to enter a valid number with the help of a do-while loop.
however, this resulted in an undeclared variable error.

Comment: Please quote the error you get, along with a [mre]. I suspect it is either telling you the solution or contradicting your first "in" from the title.

Answer (score 3):

`sp` is out of scope after the closing brace of the `{...}` block it is declared in.  You need to declare it in the same scope as the `while` statement:

```
int sp = 0 ;
do
{
    sp = get_int("Enter the start size of llama population:");
}
while (sp>=9);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless they are VLA, automatic variables have a lifetime — outside of which they can't be accessed — corresponding to the execution of their block of definition. Referring to an object outside of its lifetime has undefined behaviour.

Move the declaration of `sp` before the `while` construct.